# Modifier issue - Array curve

Tags: modeling

I was trying the to make a conveyor belt while following up the steps given in YouTube Tutorial but got stuck while applying the Modifier>Array>Curve. The plane I am trying to merge is getting inverted every time I work on it. Can you guys help me to fit it well? Below are the screenshots of what I am trying to make and what results I am getting.

[image: I am trying to make]

[image: Results, what I am getting]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/